# Rust trait extend and override in a chained inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, rust

I am extremely new to Rust (and I am loving it :p), but I am struggling with some implementation. My background is from Python, and so I am trying to apply some Inheritance-like code. For instance, in Python:

```
class A:
    def a_A_implemented_method(self):
        return "This is an implemented method from A."

    def an_abstract_method(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def a_B_implemented_method(self):
        return "This is an implemented method from B."

    def an_abstract_method(self):
        return "A's abstract method is overridden"

    def another_abstract_method(self):
        pass

class C(B):
    def a_C_implemented_method(self):
        return "This is an implemented method from C."

    def another_abstract_method(self):
        return "B's abstract method is overridden"

    def a_general_method(self):
        return "I am here to help."
```

In Rust, for similar behavior, I am trying something like (I am not still very proficient with strings, so I will keep it simple and more intended-like in the example),

```
trait A {
    fn a_A_implemented_method(&self) -> String {"This is an implemented method from A."}

    fn an_abstract_method(&self) -> String;
}

trait B {
    fn a_B_implemented_method(&slef) -> String {"This is an implemented method from B."}

    fn another_abstract_method(&self) -> String;
}

impl A for B {
    fn an_abstract_method(&self) -> String {"A's abstract method is overridden"};
}

struct C {}

trait C {
    fn a_C_implemented_method(&slef) -> String {"This is an implemented method from C."}

    fn a_general_method(&self) -> String {"I am here to help."};
}

impl B for C {
    fn an_abstract_method(&self) -> String {"A's abstract method is overridden"};
}
```

But, for many reasons, this doesn't work.

For instance, when I make `impl A for B` the compiler complain about a dyn B, but I would like to avoid this and keep thing simple (I don't believe I will need dyn B).

In `trait C`, the compiler complains that the variable name already exists, can't I have a struct and a trait with the same name? How can I have properties and methods if it is so?

Why is the compiler complaining about a dyn B? How can I avoid it?

Can you please help me understand how something like it may be implemented in Rust and fill the gaps of what I am missing?

Thank you very much for the help! :D

Comment: Hi Sergio. Usually you will not be able to apply oop patterns as you apply them in other languages. In this case `abstrac` methods cannot be overriden iirc, they will just be ambiaguated and the compiler will force you to desambiguate them.

Comment: There's no general purpose inheritance mechanism in Rust. Inheritance is used for several orthogonal reasons in languages that do support it, and Rust tends to approach those problems with orthogonal solutions. Depending on why you're using inheritance in the first place, the best Rust translation for two very similar pieces of Python code might look very different. So it's not possible to make any sweeping conclusions about toy code like this.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. As far as I know, there exists overriding in rust. My issue is related to the second inheritance, which I am unable to figure out. I know that the concept is not quite of inheritance, but something a little different. I believe that the point of my question is if can't I have a generic trait that may be specialized for different tasked that may also be further specialized? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The trait based system is somewhat at odds with inheritance from other languages.

Given that, there is a somewhat similar pattern using structs and enums that might apply here.

```
trait A {
    fn my_method(&self) -> String;
}

struct B {}

struct C {}

impl A for B {
    fn my_method(&self) -> String {
        "Hello from B".to_owned()
    }
}

impl A for C {
    fn my_method(&self) -> String {
        "Hello from C".to_owned()
    }
}
```

Somewhat like having an abstract method defined, you can create a generic method which will work with any input type that implements the desired trait.

```
pub fn greet<T: A>(t: &T) {
    println!("{}", t.my_method());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @chills42, but this example is similar to the one on the documentation A->B, A->C inheritance, but there is no A->B->C relationship which was the point of my question.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess the question is what would be gained by the A -> B -> C relationship? I bet I can refine this to clarify, but I'm not sure what the goal is?

Comment: It is hard to explain here, but the idea is that I am working in a CFD (computation fluid dynamic) code, and to solve each PDE I have this equation "class" that is inherited by others, such: energy equation, species equation, momentum equation, and so on. All these are generic and have some specialized "methods". Finally, I would like to have some freedom to restrict even further each of those equations, for instance, if I am working with a solid material, I have no speed so the convective term would not be needed. I could in this final layer select only the terms I want to solve.

Comment: Ok, I think you are wanting to create additional methods that use the specialized versions... what was in your generic class could use trait bounds to rely on those items being implemented https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/bounds.html